# Can you help me solve this using the current value Hamiltonian?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, mathematics, hamiltonian, variational-calculus, optimization

Okay, so I am getting a little stuck on this question, I will post it and then tell you how far I get.

$$
max - \int_0^2 (x^2 + u^2)e^{-0.03t}dt\,
$$

$$ 
x' = x-2u
$$

$$
x(0) = 3
$$

$$ x(2)free $$ therefore $$ p(T) = 0 $$

Okay so thats the question, we have to maximize this using the current value Hamiltonian

so I set up the Hamiltonian and take the respective derivatives

$$ H = -(x^2 + u^2)e^{^-0.03t} + p $$

$$ {d^2 H\over du^2} = -2ue^{-0.03t}-2p = 0 $$
$$-{d^2 H\over dx^2} = p' = -2xe^{-0.03t}+p $$

I sovle for $$ u(t) = pe^{0.03t} $$

and I end up with the following two equations.

$$ x' = x-2pe^{0.03t} $$
$$ p' = -2xe^{-0.03t} $$

I get the general solution as followes (which I think is wrong)

$$ x = Ae^{1/2 - \sqrt(17/2)t} + B e^{1/2 + \sqrt(17/2)t} $$
$$ p = A\sqrt(17/2)e^{1/2 - \sqrt(17/2)t} + B\sqrt(17/2)e^{1/2+\sqrt(17/2)} $$

I am pretty sure that the general solutions shouldn´t be this complecated.

If anybody can let me know if I am on the right track, that would be awesome!

Comment: I have just realised that $$p' = 2xe^{-0.03t} - p $$ so my above answer is wrong, but if anybody can still solve and check with my solution (when I get there) :)

Comment: Would [math.se] be a better home for this question?